# Apache redirection problem!

Tags: apache, zend-framework, redirect

I am setting up a pre-built website built in php. The site was actually hosted on the linux server. Now I am trying to set it up on a Window machine with WAMP server. In this website almost every page request passes through a particular file called redirect(which is basically a php file without extension).
Now the problem is that when I inspected the configuration(httpd.conf, apache.conf,.htaccess, vhost.conf etc) of the apache server on the linux machine, I nowhere found the redirect rules for doing so. Neither mod_rewrite nor mod_alias rules for this redirection were found there. But is still redirects the request properly. I also noticed that Zend Framework library is there in the exact same directory where the redirect file is. This library is included in the include_path in php.ini. However, the web site is still not developed using Zend MVC and I have seen NO proof of ZEND being used there.

So I am really confused how this redirection is working there? I am unable to set up this on window machine without rewrite rules of mod_rewrite or mod_alias. Do you guys know any alternative of both the said modules for redirection?

I know the site is really weird, but i have to set it up. :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: hidden .htaccess file in root directory?

Comment: I have checked that. There is NO redirection rule in the .htaccess file!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!!! :)

It was NGINX being used as Web Server Proxy before the request get passed to Apache daemon. So , there was NO redirect rules using mod_alias or mod_rewrite modules of Apache. The rule was written in configuration of NGINX.

It was really hard for me to find out this because the application was setup by somebody elsea and I had to fix that application. :)

Any how problem is resolved!!!!!! :)